# How to perform select from a row which is duplicate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have the following schema where there is a `person, phone and address` table. `Person` table has 1 to 0 to many relations with both `phone and address` table.
I am trying to output the following result but I am out of ideas since I am learning and doing it. How can I get the following result with this query I wrote where I get the same result but in 2 rows?

```
+------+--------+----------------+----------------+
| NAME | MRN_NB | HOME_PHONE_NBR | WORK_PHONE_NBR |
+------+--------+----------------+----------------+
| John |    222 | 415-222-3333   | 510-333-4444   |
+------+--------+----------------+----------------+
```

QUERY -

```
SELECT P.NAME, P.MRN_NB, PN.PHONE_NBR                                    
FROM PERSON  P                                  
INNER JOIN PHONE PN ON P.ID = PN.ID                                  
Where P.MRN_NB = (Select
T.MRN_NB from PERSON T inner join PHONE U on T.ID=U.ID where
U.USG_TYP='HOME' or U.USG_TYP='WORK' group by T.MRN_NB having
COUNT(T.MRN_NB)>1)
```

And what would be the modification to my query to return all rows that have a work number but without a `home` number with output like?

```
+------+--------+--------------+
| NAME | MRN_NB |  PHONE_NBR   |
+------+--------+--------------+
| Bill |    444 | 650-444-5555 |
+------+--------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first requirement i.e., Displaying two rows data in one row, we can use same table two times with `left join` -

```
select p.NAME, p.MRN_NB, ph.PHONE_NBR as HOME_PHONE_NBR, pw.PHONE_NBR as WORK_PHONE_NBR
from Person as p
left join Phone as ph on ph.ID = p.ID and ph.USG_TYPE = 'HOME'
left join Phone as pw on pw.ID = p.ID and pw.USG_TYPE = 'WORK'
```

Output -

```
NAME    MRN_NB  HOME_PHONE_NBR  WORK_PHONE_NBR
JOHN    111     2424234         6464
```

For your second requirement i.e., Displaying only that Persons who don't have `HOME` number -

```
select p.NAME, p.MRN_NB, max(pn.PHONE_NBR)
from Person as p
inner join phone as pn on pn.ID = p.ID and pn.USG_TYPE is not null
group by p.ID, p.NAME, p.MRN_NB
having sum(case pn.USG_TYPE when 'home' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Output-

```
NAME    MRN_NB  PHONE_NBR
ROHTI   222     78686
```

Comment: Thank you Ashish. For my first requirement, it shows all records in the table with null values as well. I only need to show the record who has both phone numbers and ignore rest.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this with `JOIN` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT P.NAME, P.MRN_NB, PN.PHONE_NBR                                    
FROM PERSON P INNER JOIN
     PHONE PN
     ON P.ID = PN.ID  
WHERE PN.USG_TYP = 'WORK' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM PHONE PN2
                  WHERE PN2.ID = PN.ID AND PN2.USG_TYP = 'HOME'
                 );
```